# match datetime with database datetime

Tags: php, mysql

I have a exam form. But I want to show that form within given date and time. Means if start date time is 2016-06-24 11:34:04  and end date time is 2016-06-27 00:00:00  If any merson open form between given date and time the form should be open otherwise it will go on another message page.  I have a code .But it is not working. Please help.

```
   <?php
   include("connection.php");

   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

   $timestamp = time();
   $date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);

   $result=mysql_query("select * from activeform");
                            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                extract($row);

                                if($date_time > '$startdate' and $date_time < '$enddate')
                                {
                                header("Location: myaccount.php");

                                }

                                else{

                                echo"date has been exceeds";
                                }
                                }

    ?>
```

Comment: The type of `startdate` and `enddate` is `date`?

Comment: It's not recommended to use `mysql_query`, look into PDO or the `mysqli_...` functions. Besides that, I suggest you include the conditions for the date range in the query, instead of iterating over all the results

Comment: yes, startdate and enddate is in database table name which is like 2016-06-24 11:34:04 and  2016-06-26 11:34:04. It is taking as variable in qyery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use strtotime if you would like to compare dates in PHP. You may want to look at this [answer](http://www.thetricky.net/php/Compare+dates+with+PHP)

Comment: I tried like this...if(strtotime($date_time) > strtotime('$startdate') && strtotime($date_time) < strtotime('$startdate'))  But not working.

Comment: can you try removing the single quote? something like this if((strtotime($date_time) > strtotime($startdate)) && (strtotime($date_time) < strtotime($startdate)))

Comment: thnx...its working..if(strtotime($date_time) > strtotime('$startdate') && strtotime($date_time) < strtotime('$enddate'))..... I did not place enddate with startdate.... now its working..

Comment: if this solves your problem, can you mark this answer as correct please. :)